# What is an if statement, and how can I use it effectively?

Tags: c#, c++

I'm having a hard time understanding `if` statements. What are they, and how can I use them effectively in C# and C++?

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. I recommend finding a textbook or online tutorial.

Comment: You need to learn the basics of a programming language before you can learn more advanced topics.

Comment: "Curse"? you may really want to look for other field of study if you are ready to curse when you see basic "if" statement... Also as edtheprogrammerguy edited your post you may be talking about "course" (but anyway you should remove story of your life from the post as not necessary on SO).

Comment: If you understand this comment, delete this question. ;)

Comment: You'll be wanting a copy of Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie's fine work, [The C Programming Language](http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-2nd-Edition/dp/0131103628).

Comment: Do you realize that C++ and C# are two different languages?  You might want to include other languages that support "if" statements like Pascal or FORTRAN or BASIC.  It's all the same concept.

Comment: How do you write your existing programs without them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `if` statements lets you evaluate whether a given statement is true.

```
if (statement)
{
  //do something if, and only if, the preceding statement is true
}
```

You can also extend this with the `else` keyword, which lets you do something if the `if` statement evaluates to false:

```
if (statement)
{
  //do something if the preceding statement is true
}
else
{
  //if the statement isn't true, do something else here
}
```

For example,

```
int a = 5;

if (a < 4)
{
  //code here will never run because (a < 4) is a false statement
}

if (a > 3)
{
  //code here will run because (a > 3) is a true statement
}

if (a == 5)
{
  //code here will run because (a == 5) is a true statement
}
```

As for how to use these keywords effectively... that takes time and practice to learn, the same as any other programming concept. The general idea is simple enough: use `if` when you want to see if a statement is true, and use `else` if you want to do one thing for a true statement and a different thing for a false statement. But knowing exactly *what* to evaluate is sometimes more difficult, especially in the case of multiple or complex things to evaluate.